# Backup SQL Server CE database with C# - Import-Export

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have created a C# windows application with vs2010 and I'm using a SQL Server CE database. I'm looking for a way to backup my database programmatically.

Is there a way to export/import my entire database (as a `.sdf` file) or just copy it to another location and then import it and replace the current one?Could anyone provide me the code in order to do this?

I'm relatively new to this but I'm guessing this is not something as difficult as it sounds. I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.Copy will do the job, I believe. You can get the full path from the SqlCeConnection.Database property

Comment: I read that before but i don't now how to make it work.can you give me an example?

Comment: I found how to make it work but i used an absolute path for database. I would like to use a relative path instead, for after deploying my application.How can i do this?